# Queuing a series of ajax requests as they are triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking to queue a series of AJAX requests using JQuery.
Suppose there is a function updateImage() that queries the server for a URL based on a button the user clicks, and returns a link to an image.
The server records imageId, and the browser displays the image. This application requires the order of success callback functions to trigger in the order they were sent (so that the browser displays the images corresponding with the user's click order).

To illustrate:

```
//User a number of buttons in quick succession
$(".button").click(function(){
    var imageId = $(this).attr("id");
    updateImage(imageId);               
});

//Ajax success callbacks need to run in the order of the clicks
function updateImage(imageId) {
    $.ajax({
    url: /someurl,
    data: imageId,
    success: successFunction    //this function will update the DOM
  });
}
```

I have considered $.ajaxStop, but the issue is that there are other AJAX functions that I don't want to be halted or queued because of this updateImage function. I have also looked at $.when, but that allows you to chain a known number of executions of ajax calls, but I'm not sure how many times a user will click -  I'm not sure that applies here.

Comment: did you get it figured out OP?

Comment: @r3wt I'm still working on it. I did take a look at your suggestion - ideally I'd like it to work without a setTimeout so that the iteration repeats without waiting, but I didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: why did you accept the answer? also, my answer relies on setTimeout only to act as a ratelimiter, ie( clicking 5 buttons rapidly only fires the function on the last time.

Comment: @r3wt I marked it as correct, because other than the setTimeOut which doesn't fit my particular needs (which I didn't make clear in the question), for anyone else looking at this, it works, and is clean and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This accomplishes what you want.Basically the below code does exactly what you want, a synchronous event queue with asynchronous ajax requests. be sure and fill in the `updateImage` function with whatever it is you need to do on success.

**EDIT 11/12/2015**

@_benng on twitter pointed out that my original version of this is a `pyramid of doom`. 
he's correct, since there is the possibility that queue could mutate leading to
inconsistent index problems (array changes length while click event handler is firing, 
resulting in the index changing while being used in click handler/ajax callback)
a simple remedy would be to copy the queue to a temp var and work on it, only truncating
queue when it is safe to do so without mutation. i tried to cover all the edge cases i could think of, but there is probably some that i have missed. anyways, happy coding.if problems arise, you may want to use pessimistic locking if you can figure out how to implement it in javascript. i've tried and failed many times.

```
$(function(){

    var queue = [],
    var q = {},
    var t;

    $(".button").click(function(){
        var index = queue.push({
            id: imageId,
            completed: false
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: /someurl,
            data: imageId,
            success: function(data){
                //since length is 1 based and index is 0 based
                //queue.length > index ~ queue.length >= index+1
                if(queue.length > index){
                    queue[index].completed = true;
                    $(q).trigger('completed');  
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(q).on('completed',function(){
        if(typeof t === 'number') clearTimeout(t);
        //copy queue to a temporary array.
        var copy = (function(){ return queue.slice(); }());//for the paranoid perform safe "copy" of array
        var copy_len = copy.length;//starting copy length
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            while(copy.length > 0){
                if(copy[0].completed == false) break;
                var item = copy.shift();
                updateImage(item.id);
            }

            //if queue length has changed,we could mistakenly delete unprocessed items by truncating array
            //only destroy queue if copy.length === 0 and queue.length equals starting copy length
            if(copy.length===0 &&copy_len===queue.length){
                queue.length = 0; //truncate queue only when it is "safe"
            }

        },100);


    });

    function updateImage(imageId)
    {
        //do whatever you need to do here on completion.
    }

});
```

Comment: a user on twitter pointed out how this might allow things to happen out of order in certain circumstances. i'll push a fix to the answer later on.